# Questionable Proofs in Modal LPC

Tags: proof-verification, logic, modal-logic

I'm working through some exercises in Hughes and Cresswell, and it seems that I must be making a mistake - the exercise indicates that (at least some of) the axioms of S5 should be necessary, but the following proofs show that the wff is a theorem of any normal modal logic.

The exercise asks to show that $\exists x \square (\square \varphi x\vee \psi y)\equiv \square \exists x (\square \varphi x\vee \psi y)$ is a theorem of S5. Here are the proofs which show that it is a theorem of any normal modal system:

$\aleph=_{def}\varphi x\rightarrow \square \varphi x$ is a theorem of any normal modal system:
\begin{align*}
    &(1) &&\varphi x\rightarrow \varphi x &PC\\
     &(2) &&\square \varphi x \rightarrow \square \varphi x & RPK,(1)\\
      &(3) &&\square \varphi x \rightarrow \varphi x & T\\
       &(4) &&\varphi x \rightarrow \square \varphi x& (2), (3) 
       \end{align*}
$\gimel =_{def} \alpha\rightarrow \exists x \alpha$ is a theorem of any normal modal system: 
\begin{align*} 
        &(1) &&\forall x\neg \alpha \rightarrow \neg \alpha &\forall 1\\
         &(2) &&\alpha \rightarrow \neg \forall x \neg \alpha &PC, (1)\\
          &(3) &&\alpha \rightarrow \exists x \alpha &QI, (2)\\
\end{align*}

Consequently, $\exists x \square (\square \varphi x\vee \psi y)\equiv \square \exists x (\square \varphi x\vee \psi y)$ is a theorem of any normal modal system: 
\begin{align*}
        &(1) &&(\square \varphi x \vee \psi y) \rightarrow(\square \varphi x \vee \psi y)& PC\\
         &(2) &&(\square \varphi x \vee \psi y)\rightarrow \square (\square \varphi x \vee \psi y)&\aleph\\
          &(3) &&\square (\square \varphi x \vee \psi y)\rightarrow \exists x \square (\square \varphi x \vee \psi y) &\gimel \\
           &(4) &&(\square \varphi x \vee \psi y)\rightarrow \exists x\square (\square \varphi x \vee \psi y)&PC, (2),(3)\\
          &(5) &&(\square \varphi x \vee \psi y)\rightarrow \exists x (\square \varphi x \vee \psi y)&\gimel \\
           &(6) &&\exists x(\square \varphi x \vee \psi y)\rightarrow \square \exists x (\square \varphi x \vee \psi y)&\aleph\\
             &(7) &&(\square \varphi x \vee \psi y)\rightarrow \square \exists x (\square \varphi x \vee \psi y)&PC, (5),(6)\\
           &(8) &&\exists x \square (\square \varphi x\vee \psi y)\rightarrow (\square \varphi x\vee \psi y) &PC, (1),(4)\\
          & (9) && \exists x \square (\square \varphi x\vee \psi y)\rightarrow \square \exists x (\square \varphi x\vee \psi y) &PC, (8),(7)\\
            &(10) &&(\square \varphi x\vee \psi y)\rightarrow \exists x \square (\square \varphi x\vee \psi y) &PC, (1),(4)\\
          & (11) && \square \exists x(\square \varphi x\vee \psi y)\rightarrow  \exists x \square (\square \varphi x\vee \psi y) &PC, (10), (7)\\
          & (12) && \square \exists x(\square \varphi x\vee \psi y)\equiv  \exists x \square (\square \varphi x\vee \psi y) &PC, (9), (11)
\end{align*}

Is there an obvious error in any of these three?

Comment: I don't see a justification for item (4) under $\aleph$. "Anything that is true is necessarily true"?

Comment: As Andreas indicates, $\aleph$ is not a theorem of all (or almost any) normal modal systems. In addition to the incorrectness of line (4), T is not included in the usual definition of normal modal logic.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ah, thank you, this was a silly error.